# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token (45:10) in app/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js

Tags: anchor, web3.js, spl-token

Good day! When trying to run my frontend code with yarn dev, I recently encountered an error that goes:
[image: error message]

I suspect this error to be due to some package dependency issues but I am unable to understand which packages might be erroneous. I have done unit testing on my code and it works just fine... Here are the relevant packages, if it may help!

[image: backend(top) and frontend(bottom) packages]

Thank you for the help!! :)

Comment: Have you looked into this solution? This might help: > https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/2688

Comment: are u using webpack? can you create a reproducible repo?